# List directory contents redirect to file using tee

Tags: shell-script, cron, tee

I'm having some difficulty understanding why a particular process is failing. Basically, I have a line in my script that is listing directory contents, using `tee` to redirect the output to two files:

```
retval=`ls -1 $SOURCE_DIR/${2}/${3} | tee ${COPY_LIST} ${MOVE_LIST}`
```

The command works fine on the command line and both files are populated (around 8K of lines). The strange thing is that through cron, the script just "hangs"and checking the file only a partial list of the same directories is created (approx 3k records). Last line is also partial and not written completely. Not sure whether the problem is within `tee` in itself.

```
    #!/bin/ksh
#DAILY RUN

#DEBUG_SCREEN=ON
LOG_FILE=/daily_archive_v2_`date +%d-%m-20%y`.log
. /stdlib.ksh

##the datetimestamp for the file that contains the list of files to be archived
LIST_TIMESTAMP=`perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%Y%m%d_%H%M",localtime(time());'`

Month_value=`date +%m`
typeset -i Prev_Month_value_tmp=`date +%m`
Prev_Month_value_tmp=${Prev_Month_value_tmp}-1
Year_value=`date +%y`

if [[ "${Month_value}" -eq 01 ]] then
  echo "Month is January"
  typeset -i Prev_Year_value=${Year_value}-1
Prev_Month_value_tmp=12
else
  Prev_Year_value="${Year_value}"
fi

if [[ "${Prev_Month_value_tmp}" -le 10 ]] then
  echo "Prev month is less than 10"
  Prev_Month_value="0${Prev_Month_value_tmp}"
else
  Prev_Month_value="${Prev_Month_value_tmp}"
fi
echo Previous Month Value = $Prev_Month_value

echo LOGFILE NAME SET TO $LOG_FILE
echo "DAILY REPORT [Archiving Month ${Month_value}]"
log "DAILY REPORT [Archiving Month ${Month_value}]"
log_line
SOURCE_DIR=/test
DEST_DIR=/Archives/month_"${Month_value}"_20"${Year_value}"
BACKUP_DIR=/vault/month_"${Month_value}"_20"${Year_value}"
mkdir -p $DEST_DIR
mkdir -p $BACKUP_DIR

COPY_LIST="${LIST_TIMESTAMP}_output_archiving.copy.lst"
MOVE_LIST="${LIST_TIMESTAMP}_output_archiving.move.lst"

#PARAMS : NAME, DIR, MASK
function move_files
{
  DEST_DIR=/month_"${Month_value}"_20"${Year_value}"
  FILES_COUNT=`ls -1 $SOURCE_DIR/$2/$3 | wc -l`
  if [ "${FILES_COUNT}" != "0" ]; then
    log "MOVE $FILES_COUNT $1 FILES $SOURCE_DIR/$2/$3 to $DEST_DIR/$2"
    log "MOVE $FILES_COUNT $1 FILES $SOURCE_DIR/$2/$3 to $BACKUP_DIR/$2"
    mkdir -p $DEST_DIR/$2
    mkdir -p $BACKUP_DIR/$2
retval=`ls -1 $SOURCE_DIR/${2}/${3} | tee ${COPY_LIST} ${MOVE_LIST}`
#echo retval=`ls -1 $SOURCE_DIR/${2}/${3} | tee ${COPY_LIST} ${MOVE_LIST}`
#       while read line
#         do
#         CURRENT_FILE=`echo $line`
#         #echo ${CURRENT_FILE}
#         cp -p ${CURRENT_FILE} $BACKUP_DIR/$2
#         mv ${CURRENT_FILE} $DEST_DIR/$2
#         log "File ${CURRENT_FILE} copied to $BACKUP_DIR/$4/"
#         log "File ${CURRENT_FILE} moved to $DEST_DIR/$4/"
#         done < ${COPY_LIST}
  else
    echo Nothing to move
  fi
#        gzip  $DEST_DIR/$2/*
#         gzip $BACKUP_DIR/$2/*
}

move_files  "TESTDIR" "dir2/test" "*.txt"

\rm -f $RESULTS_FILE
\rm -f $FILE_LIST
#rm -f $LOG_FILE
```

Comment: How is the script invoked from your `crontab` and what are the values of the various variables?

Comment: Add an `echo` to the beginning of the line and redirect the script's output to a file (in the crontab, write `/path/to/script > /tmp/script.log`), then see what command you are actually running.

Comment: @Kusalananda  - the values are just paths to the files. Variables are correctly set since both file lists are created but with incomplete data, so its not an issue with the variables.

Comment: @terdon no errors are returned, added the echo and only the normal script loggin/echos are returned. I will try and use find maybe its an issue with the long list of files that are returned with ls maybe that is messing things out

Comment: @Etienne that's one possibility, but I doubt it's the number of files returned, [parsing `ls` is almost always a very bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). But please [edit] your question and show us the exact command being run by `cron`. We need to see what  `ls -1 $SOURCE_DIR/${2}/${3} | tee ${COPY_LIST} ${MOVE_LIST}` is expanded to when run by `cron` so please add `echo "ls -1 $SOURCE_DIR/${2}/${3} | tee ${COPY_LIST} ${MOVE_LIST}"` to your script and add the output to your question.

Comment: Remove the assignment to the variable `retval` and direct to a file as in this way `ls -1 $SOURCE_DIR/${2}/${3} > ${COPY_LIST} ${MOVE_LIST}` Then examine the size of the file to see any errors there. Causing such a large amounts of files in variable substitutions clogs the memory and slows thing down.

Comment: @terdon, its not a cron issue only, running the script standalone results in the same problem as in partial information is written in the log files. (sorry I was not 100% clear when posting the question). The command works fine if its run directly on its own.

Comment: @Rakesh - you were right here, I removed the variable assignment and the files contained all the expected information. Why returning this number of information is clogging the memory ? Do you think using find will sort it out or any other particular method to use. I was using the variable assignment as to be able to do a while loop to read line by line the file.

Comment: @Etienne please show us the entire script. There are many different things that can break this, the most obvious being any file names with spaces. And if you're doing something like this, it is a pretty good indication that there are other issues in the script.

Comment: @terdon - done, there is some code that is commented - basically that is to avoid entering the loop while testing.

Comment: does your actual script have a semicolon before `then` on line 16: `if [[ "${Month_value}" -eq 01 ]] then` ?